# How to calculate average of rows in table and add specifc row to input?

Tags: sql

I have rows of averages for all countries, I try to calculate the average of all averages and add the row of the specific input.

I was able to calculate the average of all countries by aggregation and average action, but I do not know how to add a specific line of input.

The input:

[image]

the output:

```
| Country    |     Average      |
|  All       |   1.72096666666  |
|  GB        |   1.64992311635  |
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? (Let me know if I've missed your point):

```js
(YOUR_AGGEGATE_QUERY_GOES_HERE)
UNION
(SELECT CountryRegionCode as Country, AverageOrdersPerCostumer as Average FROM table_name
WHERE CountryRegionCode = "GB")
```

You can tweak the WHERE statement if you want to use row id instead but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using oracle data base, then you can try using rollup aggregate function which will fit exactly for your requirement ...

Below is the link for your reference...

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28313/aggreg.htm#i1007413

https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets

Answer (score 0):

this will surely work:

```
select 'ALL',avg(averageorderpercustomer) from tablename group by 
countryregioncode union
select countryregioncode,averageorderpercustomer from tablename  where 
countryregioncode=5;
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
SELECT 'All' as Country, AVG(AverageOrdersPerCostumer) as Average
FROM t
UNION ALL
SELECT CountryRegionCode as Country, AverageOrdersPerCostumer as Average
FROM table_name
WHERE CountryRegionCode = 'GB';
```

As a best practice, you should use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`.

I also note that the average you are taking is the average of averages.  The countries have different sizes, so this is probably different from the average not considering countries.

Comment: same as i have written!!